# Как правильно оформить цитату?

Tags: цитирование

Возможно ли так встраивать цитату в предложение?

Петр I издал Указ: «С владельцев дорожных памяток брать прогонные деньги», а если они ехали по личным делам, то двойные прогонные.

Или более правильной будет следующая редакция предложения:

Петр I издал Указ «с владельцев дорожных памяток брать прогонные деньги», а если они ехали по личным делам, то двойные прогонные.

Или просто разбить на два?

Comment: Alenka, а Вы уверены, что цитата из указа Вами воспроизведена правильно? Попробовал погуглить -- ничего похожего не нашёл.

Comment: Может быть и нет, ведь эту цитату приводила не я... Я наоборот думаю, что и "двойные прогонные" надо заключить в кавычки...

Comment: _Может быть и нет, ведь эту цитату приводила не я..._ === Ну а если нет, то правильнее будет обойтись без кавычек. Вариант: _Петр I издал указ  о взимании с владельцев..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Хотел как комментарий оформить, но вроде бы тянет на ответ, пусть и неполный.*

*Или это у меня заскок* - да, скорее всего. ))) Никаких ограничений на этот счет правила не содержат. Другой  вопрос, нужно ли тут двоеточие по смыслу. Зависит от того, воспринимаете ли Вы (автор) цитату как условное название или же тут просто содержание раскрывается. Если второе, то двоеточие обосновано, иначе лучше без него.

Вот что касается точности цитаты - не знаю. В принципе кавычки в некоторых случаях не означают буквальную точность цитируемого, а лишь смысловую близость к тексту или просто краткое содержание. Так что можно оставить. Но лучше уточнить у автора. Если цитата неточная, то во избежание недоразумений это стоит оговорить.

Comment: Спасибо большое )))

Answer (score 0):

Если вас интересует, со строчной или прописной буквы должна начинаться цитата, то в данном случае цитату надо писать с прописной.

Comment: Нет. Я думала встроить цитату без двоеточия на правах компонента предложения или просто разбить исходное предложение на два, потому что не уверена, можно ли продолжать предложение после цитаты, данной после двоеточия... Или это у меня заскок?